# what is the way to reuse same code multiple times in jquery html

Tags: jquery, function

like below code i have to do 90 calculations how can i do this calculations with less code

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
$("#btn").click(function () {
var v1 = parseInt($("#1val").val());
var v2 = parseInt($("#2val").val());
var sum = v1 + v2;
$("#result").text(sum);
console.log(sum);

var v1 = parseInt($("#1val2").val());
var v2 = parseInt($("#2val2").val());
var sum1 = v1 + v2;
$("#result1").text(sum);
console.log(sum1);

var v1 = parseInt($("#1val3").val());
var v2 = parseInt($("#2val3").val());
var sum2 = v1 + v2;
$("#result2").text(sum);
console.log(sum2);
});
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvm7E.png)

Answer (score 0):

First you identify a pattern in the id's set then run a for loop, thats it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    [1, 2, 3].forEach(x => {
      let sum = 0;
      [1, 2].forEach(y => {
        const val = $(`#${y}val${x === 1 ? '' : x}`) && $(`#${y}val${x === 1 ? '' : x}`).val();
        sum += parseInt(val || 0);
      });
      $(`#result${x === 1 ? '' : x}`).val(sum);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="1val" />
<input id="2val" />
<input id="result" />
<input id="1val2" />
<input id="2val2" />
<input id="result2" />
<input id="1val3" />
<input id="2val3" />
<input id="result3" />
<button id="btn">submit</button>
```

Comment: yes its working but i have to do n number off calculations please help me i am stuck here from last 2 day

Comment: @sonalighadge can't help you without complete html structure, I would suggest just getting the nth child input and doing this process

Comment: var v1 = parseInt($("#c3").val());
      var v2 = parseInt($("#c1").val());
      var sum1 = v1 / v2;
      $("#result2").text(sum1);
      console.log(sum1);

      var v1 = parseInt($("#d5").val());
      var v2 = parseInt($("#d1").val());
      var sum2 = v1 / v2;
      $("#result3").text(sum2);
      console.log(sum2);

      var v1 = parseInt($("#e5").val());
      var v2 = parseInt($("#e1").val());
      var sum2 = v1 / v2;
      $("#result3").text(sum2);
      console.log(sum2);